# Jquery- add css onclick only work on first click

Tags: jquery, css

Having two label, I want them to rotate on click. I used JQuery to to that but it works only on first click!
how can I make it to work on every click?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#male", function() {
    $('#male i').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(360deg)'
    })
  })
});
```

```css
#male i,
#female i {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<label id="male" class="pull-left text-center col-md-5 btn btn-default" style="height: 36px;">
  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-male text-center" style="color: tomato">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>
  </i>
</label>
<label id="female" class="pull-right text-center col-md-5 btn btn-default" style="height: 36px;">
  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-female text-center" style="color: purple">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
  </i>
 </label>
```

Comment: It does work on every click. The first click takes the icon and rotates it from 0 to 360. The second takes the icon and rotates it from 360 to 360.

Comment: @zzzzBov oh damn! you're right! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maleRotation = 0;
$(document).on("click", "#male", function () {
        maleRotation+= 360;
        $('#male i').css({
            'transform': 'rotate('+maleRotation+'deg)'
        })
    })
```